# VbScript hta - Open a new hta by link and retrieve correct filename

Tags: filenames, hta

I have two files; "1.hta" and "2.hta".

"1.hta" contains a simple link to file "2.hta"

```
<a href="2.hta">2.hta</a>
```

"2.hta" contains a script to determine its own filename

```
FullName = replace(oApp.commandLine,chr(34),"")  'oApp = HT Application ID
arrFN=split(FullName,"\")  
FileName = arrFN(ubound(arrFN))  
SourceDir=replace(FullName,FileName,"")
```

"2.hta" works perfectly when started "stand-alone" --> FileName = 2.hta

However, starting "2.hta" via link from "1.hta" I get --> FileName = 1.hta

I need a way to determine the correct filename, or does hta always retrieve the filename of the first/starting instance?

Comment: I slightly improved the formatting wording of your question. Please review my changes to ensure they work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA Launch another HTA</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
</head>
<SCRIPT Language="vbscript">
Sub Execute(File)
 Dim ws
 Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
 ws.run chr(34) & File & chr(34)
End sub
</SCRIPT>
<body>
<h1>This is test hta 1 ONE</h1>
<a href="#" onClick="Call Execute('2.hta')">Start the HTA2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This requires `singleInstance` to be set, if it is not allowed, wouldn't it be easier just to extract the file name from `location.href`, no need to start a new mshta process.

Comment: THX Hackoo, code works and YES, "location.href" is easier and the hint I was after... :)